# How to find remainder?

Tags: java, c, algorithm, math, numbers

I want to find a remainder of very long numbers .I am writing a program for this and as I cannot find the remainder directly due to the fact that they are large numbers (in c) .How can I do this?the limit for the number from which I have to divide the bigger number to find remainder is 500.i.e 1 to 500
I thought of dividing the number like this:

> 1234567=1*10^6+2*10^5+...
>
> 1234567%x=1modx*10^6modx+2modx*10^5modx...

I need a better way than this.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Comment: I need a more specific answer then this :)

Comment: Use the modulo operator %

Comment: Please [edit] in your code so we can see how to help!

Comment: The problem is that I cannot store the value as integer or long as its huge..right now I have the value in string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
Use a linked list. Store the number as a group of numbers dynamically.
For eg:

112233445566778899001122 =>  11223344 55667788 99001122

Now consider the individual unit and start from left to right. Find the reminder and manipulate it to add to the next group and go on.

Now implementation is very easy :)

Edit:

```
 112233445566778899001122/6 =>  11223344 55667788 99001122/6


 11223344/6 =>2

 2*100000000 + 55667788 = 255667788
 255667788/6 => 0
 0*100000000 + 99001122 = 99001122
 99001122/6=>0

 So the reminder is 0.
```

Remember, the individual unit after manipulation should be under the maximum range **int** can support.

Comment: can you tell me little about the manipulation..that seems to be a tough task

Comment: @user3851486: If you are satisfied with the answer, upvote it :)

Comment: @user3851486: Can I get the best answer too :P

Answer (score 0):

If your question regards using very long or large numbers try using something a `long long`. The problem could be that the data type that you are using is too small to hold the values that you require.

You could try using a bignum library like [GMP](https://gmplib.org/) or another kind of ugly way in comparison would be to use arrays or lists, somewhat similar to [this](http://www.cquestions.com/2010/08/write-c-program-to-find-factorial-of.html).

Other than that, the modulo operation `%` will calculate the remainder for you.

Comment: it may contain 10000 digits.

Comment: Ok. Try a big num library then. Something like [GMP](https://gmplib.org/). For help perhaps look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440093/how-to-find-the-remainder-of-large-number-division-in-c) as well.

Comment: I don't want to use such libraries.Do you have any other solution?

Comment: Developers need libraries @user3851486
Some things (like this) can't be achieved without them.

Comment: You could probably use an array. Does [this](http://www.cquestions.com/2010/08/write-c-program-to-find-factorial-of.html) help?

Comment: you could write your own small version of GMP, but don't quite see the reason why